# How to use jQuery to fade in/out li a:hover css background-color?

Tags: jquery, css, fade

I have been struggling with a problem for a couple of days now with no success so decided to sign up here and see if some kind soul can help me out. Fingers crossed!

I am trying to animate (fade in/out) the css background-color of a link in an unordered list when it is hovered over. It is essential to maintain the unordered list structure so I am not looking for a solution that separates each link into it's own div and animates the background colour of that.

I would also like to restrict the solution to animating the css rather than the entire solution being in js in order that it degrades simply and gracefully if js is turned off.

I have a simple unordered nav list like this:

```
<div id="projectContent">
    <ul class="listings">
        <li><a href="*">Another Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="*">Year</a></li>
        <li><a href="*">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="*">Country</a></li>
        <li><a href="*">Area</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
#projectContent .listings{display:block; width:780px; border-top:1px solid #008BFD;     margin:0; padding:0; float:left}
#projectContent .listings li{list-style:none; padding:0; line-height:1.6em}
#projectContent .listings li a{display:block; width:780px; color:#969991; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px solid #666; float:left; padding:0 0 1px 0;background-color:#F5F5F5; }
#projectContent .listings a:hover{background-color:#008BFD; color:#fff;}
```

So far so good - however I have searched high and low for a tutorial/plugin which will allow me to quickly (say 50-100 ms) fade in the background-color when the links are hovered over and fade it out slowly (say 500-1000ms) when the cursor moves off the link.

I have found many tutorials which fade in out a background image on a link but nearly all of them involve each link being in it's own div or span and I don't want to do that...

I have found a couple of tutorials which I think are close to what I am looking for but unfortunately they don't provide demos so hard to be sure...I understand I need to be using both the main jQuery script and either the jQuery color plugin or the core UI - I have tried both without success.

Here are some examples of jQuery I have tried:

```
var originalBG = $("#projectContent .listings li a").css("background-color");
var fadeColor = "#008BFD"; 

$("#projectContent .listings li a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor}, 450 )
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate( {backgroundColor: originalBG}, 950 )
    }
);
```

and this which is very similar but I was trying to specify the hover/fade color in the css...

```
var originalBG = $("#projectContent .listings li a").css("background-color");
var fadeColor = $("#projectContent .listings li a:hover").css("background-color");

$("#projectContent .listings li a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate( { backgroundColor:fadeColor}, 100 )
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate( {backgroundColor: originalBG}, 900 )
    }
);
```

I also tried this but the colours are specified in the js rather than the css which is not ideal...

```
$('.listings li a').hover(
    function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'});
    },
    function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#008BFD'});
    }
);
```

So far I have had no luck whatsoever getting anything to have any effect on my links at all!. I am very new to jQuery so probably doing something very simple wrong but would really appreciate some help from the experts here.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just use CSS3 transitions? No JS at all. The fading effect wouldn't work in IE, but it's a much cleaner way of implementing. And it degrades just fine.

```
a {
   background: #f5f5f5;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a:hover {
   background: #008BFD;
}
```

Comment: Yes - good point and I had actually already tried that and got a fairly good result - BUT - I couldn't figure out how (and not sure if it's possible to) have different speeds for fade in and out - i.e. fast fade in and slow fade out...

Comment: Just put a different transition time on `:hover`. http://jsfiddle.net/nkorth/gk5uL/

Comment: This is excellent and works perfectly - thank you both very much. If it weren't for IE I would consider the problem solved - as it is I would still like to get the js version working for that reason...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this?
[jQuery css fade](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations)

Demo here: [Demo link](http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/)

Comment: Thanks - Almost but not quite - I am trying to achieve the effect without using a background image. I would have thought it would be possible just by changing the opacity of the bg color?

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties):

> ### Animation Properties and Values
>
> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used).

Comment: Thanks - as stated in my original post I am aware I need the jQuery color plugin (or core UI) and I have tried both without success...

Comment: Oh sorry, totally missed that point! However, it does work at least for me (after adding the `$("#projectContent .listings li a").animate({backgroundColor: originalBG}, 0);` line): http://jsfiddle.net/BgQhm/1/

Comment: Good solution, but the jsfiddle you posted really needs `$(...).stop().animate(...)`, or else all the mouseovers will pile up and look really odd!

Comment: OK this is very weird - I can see your example working on jsfiddle.net - but when I put this in my own page it doesn't work (at least for me)...Have a look here: http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/fadelinktest/linktest7.html can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I can't help feeling I'm due for a big headslap...

Comment: Also - realise I want to animate the text color as well as the background color...

Comment: er...in a possibly related issue if I go here and click run on the color animations demo - it doesn't work for me.. http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Color_Animations I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.2 and not working in Safari or Firefox - this is very odd no?

Comment: Just to be clear - The other animations on that docs.jquery page I linked to above do work for me... only the color animation one does not.

Comment: @Spirit, the reason your page isn't working is that you're running the javascript before the body has been loaded. Wrap the javascript in the header inside `$(function () { ... });`

Comment: And the example in the jQuery docs has linked to a non-existing jQuery color, so it doesn't work either.

Comment: Felix - thank you so much. As I suspected a big Doh! headslap is certainly in order...jQuery 101 - wait for the document to be ready...

Comment: @nkorth - thanks for your help too. So glad I signed up here - got 2 excellent solutions to my problem. Much appreciated.