# jQuery - Changing brightness of the colors when hovering

Tags: jquery, button, dynamic, hover, brightness

Well, I have a social icon list, for example.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="social-icons">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="facebook-icon"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="twitter-icon"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="googleplus-icon"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.social-icons {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF;
 }

.facebook-icon {
    background: #3b5998;
 }

.twitter-icon {
    background: #00aced;
 }

.googleplus-icon {
    background: #dd4b39;
 }
```

**And we get this :**

[image]

Now I want to make a script that will increase the brightness of the background color for every icon when hovering, without having me manually writing new CSS lines with color codes for hover.

Also I don't want to use any others CSS methods like opacity, image masks or filters. It should be all done from JS.

Comment: without writing any new code, I don't think it is possible

Comment: I am sure that could be a way of jQuery to detect the background colors of the icons and then increase the brightness of that color somehow ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be about what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/u41qxo1e/

I created helper functions to darken/lighten (with this, you do not need any new js libraries)

```
$( ".social-icons li a i" ).hover(  
      function() {   
        //OnHover 
        $( this ).css("background-color", LightenDarkenColor(rgb2hex($( this ).css("background-color")), 20)); 
      }, function() {    
        //AfterHover
        $( this ).css("background-color", LightenDarkenColor(rgb2hex($( this ).css("background-color")), -20)); 
      });
```

Comment: Maybe you'll find what you want here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287806/how-to-use-jquery-to-fade-in-out-li-ahover-css-background-color

Answer (score 1):

Using just Javascript you can refer to this previous question:

[Increase CSS brightness color on click with jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833624/increase-css-brightness-color-on-click-with-jquery-javascript)

I hope it help.